# Split a SQLite row bij given delimiter

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm written a "movie" program in VB.NET

Users will be able to create custom filters where they can specify which movies they want to see in a list based on some simple things like genre, director, release year etc.

Table movie's:

```
ID     Title     Director     Year     Genres      Description     Image
```

Since a movie (or tv show) can have more genres I ended up with storing the the genres into 1 string with a ; as delimiter.

Example:

```
a01;a02;b08;c01
```

Of course my application converts a01 to the appropriate "Horror" or "Thriller" genre etc. etc. on retrieving the results.

My question is: is it possible to create a SQLite query that does the filtering itself? At the moment I'm creating queries like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `movies` 
WHERE (`Year` = 2013) 
  AND (`Genres` LIKE '%a02%' OR `Genres` LIKE '%g05%')
```

This does the trick, however based on some custom filters, you can end up with queries over 10kb of chars.

Is there some sort of SPLIT function in SQLite so that I could query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `movies` 
WHERE (`Year` = '2013') 
  AND (SPLIT(`Genres`,';') IN ('a01','v05','c01'))
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

*[Sorry for the T-SQL, but MS SQL Server is all I have to demonstrate with. The SQL should be very similar if not the same for SQLite.]*

What you should really do is create another table for the genres:

[image]

Then you query it with something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.[ID] AS [ID], [Title] AS [Title] FROM Movies AS M
JOIN [MovieGenre] AS MG
ON M.ID = MG.ID
WHERE (MG.Genre IN ('A01', 'A02'))
AND M.[Year] = 2010
```

From what I can tell with a quick look, it is a bit fiddly to split strings into a table in SQLite [How to split comma-separated value in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24260285/1115360) - note the comments.

However, if you can, then you can use something like

```
-- This is a temporary table in SQL Server.
-- It is only to illustrate joining onto a table of
-- user-selected genres
CREATE TABLE #genres
(
    Genre NCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO #genres VALUES ('A01');
INSERT INTO #genres VALUES ('B01');

-- The query:
SELECT DISTINCT M.[ID] AS [ID], [Title] AS [Title] FROM Movies AS M
JOIN [MovieGenre] AS MG
ON M.ID = MG.ID
JOIN #genres AS TempG
ON TempG.Genre = MG.Genre
AND M.[Year] = 2010
```

where the `#genres` table is the table you get from splitting the string.

**However** as you are creating the queries in VB.NET, you can split the string easily in that and use it to build an `IN` clause as a string easily enough - a small code sample to illustrate that:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim userSelectedGenres = "A01;A02"
        Dim gs = userSelectedGenres.Split(";"c)
        Dim inClause = String.Join(",", gs.Select(Function(g) "'" & g & "'"))

        Dim sqlString = <sql>SELECT DISTINCT M.[ID] AS [ID], [Title] AS [Title] FROM Movies AS M
JOIN [MovieGenre] AS MG
ON M.ID = MG.ID
WHERE (MG.Genre IN (<%= inClause %>))
AND M.[Year] = 2010
</sql>.Value

        Console.WriteLine(sqlString)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.[ID] AS [ID], [Title] AS [Title] FROM Movies AS M
JOIN [MovieGenre] AS MG
ON M.ID = MG.ID
WHERE (MG.Genre IN ('A01','A02'))
AND M.[Year] = 2010
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ive tried it with different tables, Ive even tried it with a "Virtual Database" but that gave me massive performance issues with the rest of the program, also: the database with data is stored localy on user pc's, altering every user db just doesn't seem a smart thing to do. I guess i'm stuck with the long query for this case